# Flash NodeMCU v3 without tools

Tags: linux, esp8266, nodemcu

I've got NodeMCU v3 board with ESP8266 chip on it. I'd like to flash it with my firmware through usb without using any tool like esptool. How can I do this from Linux?

I've got several questions:

1) Can I just write for example to /dev/ttyUSB0? Will board get this signal?

2) What should I send before sending 
binary? How to tell to board that I want to flash it?

Answer (score 1):

It won't work to just write the file to a /dev device. That's why we have flashing tools, to deal with setting up the board and properly transmitting the binary to it. To do what you're asking you'd have to write your own flashing tools. What's the problem with just using the existing ones?

Comment: It's just interesting for me to understand how it works and do it myself. I just can't find any information about flashing. How can I communicate with it? How to set it up and properly transmit binary to it?